# Git inserts junk meta tags inside the files after pull

Tags: git, ubuntu

I have been experiencing the following problem when updating a local repository with PULL operation in GIT .I work on local files.Then some team member which works from remote submits the updated version to the remote master.I pull it then, to update and merge with my local stuff.After this I usually get notifications about conflicts etc.I do add -A ,commit -a and when I look into local files ,only those that I worked on, I can see git database meta tags like HEAD >>>>>>>>>>> and commit number appear inline (php classes)and make the whole file corrupted .I thought it was something related to permissions (working on UBUNTU ).So I opened the whole permission to all files (chmod -R 777) .But still getting this issue.Once again ,it happens only with those local files which I modified.Being a noob with GIT and Linux would appreciate any helpful input on the subject.
Thanks.

Comment: As everyone said these are conflict markers. You should also ceck out git mergetool and a good merge tool such as meld, kdiff3, kompare, ordiffuse. There are lots of others so find one you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are conflict markers - git uses them to indicate where your local changes conflicted with those pulled from the repository.
See [how to merge git conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-do-i-fix-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Comment: Thanks Frank and @Quentin ,your info was really helpful

Answer (score 4):

That isn't junk, those are the conflicts that you were warned about.

Because there were two separate edits to the same part of the same file, the files couldn't be merged automatically. You need to manually [resolve the conflicts](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#resolving-a-merge) and then check the properly merged versions in.